# encode ASCII symbols into UTF-8 presentation

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, compression, ascii

I have a string that I k'now for sure has only `ASCII` lettes.
`JS` treats strings as `UTF-8` by default,
so it means that every character takes up to 4 bytes,
which is 4 times ASCII.

I'm trying to **compress** / **save spaces** / **get the shortest string as possible**,
by having an `encode` and `decode` functions.

I thought about representing 4 characters of `ASCII` on a `UTF-8` string and by that achieve my goals, is there anything like that?
[image: UTS-8 compressed to ASCII]

If not, what is the best way to compress `ASCII` strings, so that by encoding and decoding I'll reach the same string?

Answer (score 1):

Actually JavaScript encodes program strings in UTF-16, which uses 2 octets (16 bits) for Unicode characters in the BMP  (Basic Multilingual Plane) and 4 octets (32 bits) for characters outside it. So internally at least, ASCII characters use 2 bytes.

There is room to pack two ASCII characters into 16 bits since they only use 7 bits each. Furthermore, since the difference between `2**16` and `2**14` is `49152`, and the number of encodings used by surrogate pairs in UTF-16 is ([allegedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))) `2048`, you should be able to devise an encoding scheme that avoids the range of code points used by surrogates.

You could also use 8 bit [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) to hold ASCII characters while avoiding the complexity of a custom compression algorithm.

The purpose of compressing 7 bit ASCII for use within JavaScript is largely (entirely?) academic these days and not something there is a demand for. Note that encoding 7 bit ASCII content into UTF-8 (for transmission or file encoding) only uses one byte for ASCII characters due to the design of UTF-8.

Comment: Two notes: "UTF-16" is a simplification: JS have duplicate string function, one of old UCS-2 and the new UTF-16 (you may find: "code-unit" and "code-point" to make "explicit" which interpretation is using JS (for a specific function). Note two: internally JS may use more optimized types (but transparently).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The [Unicode Glossary](https://unicode.org/glossary/) covers the difference between code points and units. JavaScript was written for UCS-2 which explains why `String.prototype` methods such as `charAt` and `charCodeAt` work with code units, and `string.length` returns the number of code units in a string rather than characters.  The `String.prototype.codePointAt` method was part of extending UCS-2 to  UTF-16 string encoding, but the method's argument is in code units. I doubt that JavaScript optimizations go as far as altering the 16 bit size of string code units.

Comment: I do not know about optimization, but Python does it (and Python it is not so heavily optimized as JS, and both exchanges implementation ideas).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 1 byte per character you can simply use a byte.  There is already a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to change to a string from bytes.